# Enable notifications / Watch a Google Play bucket to programatically download reports

Tags: google-play, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

There's a lot of new information regarding [how to programatically download Google Play reports](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=crash_export&rd=1#export) using [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) tool. Google Play uses a bucket to store these reports, just like Google Cloud Storage does. I'm already able to download reports from Google Play bucket without a problem. For example:

```
gsutil cp gs://pubsite_prod_rev_<my project id>/stats/installs/installs_<my app id>_201502_overview.csv .
```

On the other hand, gsutil offers a feature to [watch Google Cloud Storage buckets](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/notification), so you can receive notifications every time an object in the bucket changes (`gsutil notification watchbucket`). I am also able to enable notifications in buckets created in my own Google Cloud projects.

**The problem is, I'm not able to enable notifications in my Google Play bucket. Is it even possible? I get an `AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden` error when calling:**

```
gsutil notification watchbucket -i playnotif -t sometoken https://notif.mydomain.com gs://pubsite_prod_rev_<my project id>
```

- I've followed all the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification), being specially careful with those regarding [identifying a domain to receive notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification?&_ga=1.251148678.1618736561.1415004064#_Authorize_Endpoint).
- As I mentioned above, I'm already able to do all the process I need, but with my own buckets in Google Cloud, not with the Google Play bucket.
- The Google Play project has been linked to a Google Cloud project. It did so automatically when I enabled Google Play API access (Google Play Developer Console -> Configuration (left menu) -> API access).
- The Google Play project owner and my own Google Cloud project owner is the same.
- This owner has successfully registered and validated the domain used to receive the notifications (following the example, I validated both just in case: `notif.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com`, using https in the [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/))
- These domains have also been whitelisted in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/?_ga=1.56956074.1618736561.1415004064) (left sidebar -> APIs & Auth -> Push).
- I've successfully enabled notifications in my own Google Cloud buckets using either the project owner account or a service account I created. I've already tried using both (owner and a corresponding service account) in the Google Play bucket, without success.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I had already followed the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Application_Example), but using different procedures (as explained in the comment below). Following Nikita's suggestion, I tried to follow the steps using the same procedure.

So I configured gsutil (through gcloud) to use the owner account:

```
gcloud config set account owner-of-play-store-project@gmail.com
```

and while trying to grant full access to the service account, I encountered this error:

```
$ gsutil acl ch -u my-play-store-service-account@developer.gserviceaccount.com:FC gs://pubsite_prod_rev_my-bucket-id
CommandException: Failed to set acl for gs://pubsite_prod_rev_my-bucket-id/. Please ensure you have OWNER-role access to this resource.
```

So, I tried to list the default ACL for this bucket, and found:

```
$ gsutil defacl get gs://pubsite_prod_rev_my-bucket-id
No default object ACL present for gs://pubsite_prod_rev_my-bucket-id. This could occur if the default object ACL is private, in which case objects created in this bucket will be readable only by their creators. It could also mean you do not have OWNER permission on gs://pubsite_prod_rev_my-bucket-id and therefore do not have permission to read the default object ACL.
[]
```

**Conclusion:**

It really makes me think that, even using the project owner account, this account doesn't have the OWNER role on the Play Store bucket.  This means ACLs can't be modified, not even listed, as well as notifications can't be enabled since, sadly, we don't really *own* the bucket.

Comment: Can you try gsutil to [use a Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Using_Account) and then follow the [Client App Sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Application_Example) to discard the possibility of domain identification issue?

Comment: @NikitaUchaev I did follow those steps although using a different procedure for each step (for example, I used POSTMAN instead of curl, granted full access to the service account through the Google Cloud Console instead of using gsutil, confirmed notifications worked looking at apache logs, etc). I succeeded when following those steps when creating my own bucket. If I follow the same steps with Play Store bucket (and its corresponding service account), it fails.  Nevertheless, trying to follow your example, I found useful errors trying to set the ACL with gsutil. Details in edited post. Thx!

Comment: Yes, based on the message returned by "gsutil defacl get" it looks like you don't have owner permissions for the bucket, hence you're not able to set watch.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you cannot. Google Play owns these buckets, and end users do not have the bucket `FULL_CONTROL` access necessary to subscribe to [Object Change Notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification).