# Google Play Developer Console

Tags: google-play, google-play-developer-api

is there any option at "google play developer console" account through which i can get a notification(in the form of email for example) When somebody downloads one of my apps through the play-store.?

Comment: not directly, you can get notification when user reviews your app. you need to customized gsutil to get customized notification on downloads, see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855617/enable-notifications-watch-a-google-play-bucket-to-programatically-download-re

Comment: thank you very much for your clarification