# Programmatically check if Google Play Console statistics reports have been updated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

#### Context

I use `gsutil` to programatically download the statistics reports provided by Google for the apps I published on the Google play store (with the command `gsutil -m -q cp -r gs://pubsite_prod_rev_<number>/* <destination folder>`, and parse them with a python script to generate plots.

#### Goal

The statistics reports are updated by Google everyday. I would like to generate the new verson of the plots as soon as new data has been published by Google.

#### Question

The time of the day Google publishes the new data is not fixed. I'm looking for a way to check if the new data has been published, ideally before downloading them entirely.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29294720/9816072), it seems impossible to directly monitor the bucket. This discussion is clearly beyond my understanding though, so I would like to ask if there's still a way to achieve that, one way or another.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable notifications / Watch a Google Play bucket to programatically download reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28855617/enable-notifications-watch-a-google-play-bucket-to-programatically-download-re)

Comment: Stack overflow answers get edited when they are out of date. So usually (including this time) if a question says it is impossible and hasn't been edited or commented on, or an alternative answer provided it is still true.